# How to convert str to int in Python list

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
a = ['1','2','4','3','7','5']
```

I want to convert str to int.

In fact, I want to write a function that multiplies a number in the list elements.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar You should mention what is wrong with the question.

Comment: Why not just store ints in the list to begin with?

Comment: You can use `int(value)` function or `eval(value)` function

Comment: @Deadpool best to not recommend `eval` at the best times for advanced/weird stuff - let alone in this context...

Comment: Check [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better answers if you show your effort and tell us what methods you have explored so far. Anyway, since the answer is already given, one more way is to use `map` like `int_a = map(int, a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn a string to an integer you can just use the built-in `int(x)` function (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)).

To do it to your whole list try:

```py
[int(x) for x in a]
```