# Converting Elements of a list without quotes (i.e. String type) to list of integer elements

Tags: python

I was writing some coding challenge where I was asked to take list of values as the input using STDIN and print even numbers using STDOUT
My language is Python and I wrote the following code

```
list1 = input() 
print(list1)
#[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

#a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

even_nos = [num for num in a if num % 2 == 0] 
print(even_nos)
```

it throws an error invalid literal for int base 10:'['

When I Checked for print(type(list1[2]) it shows <Class 'str'>

I tried to convert each element of list1 into integers using split() but it didn't work out

Can someone tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert str to int in python list python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53797339/how-to-convert-str-to-int-in-python-list-python)

Comment: show the sample input

Comment: sample input is automatically taken. i.e. list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] but these elements are in string format without quotes. It was known to me when I printed type(list1[0])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
even_nos=[]
for i in list1:
    if i.isdigit() and int(i)%2==0:
        even_nos.append(int(i))
print(even_nos)
```

try this..here you check for digit and if it is digit then check for even number.. if it is even you can append it to your list

in a list comprehension

```
even_nos=[int(num) for num in list1 if num.isdigit() if int(num)%2==0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you were given the prompt you entered '[x,y]' instead of numbers
Also you are asking for strings which you cannot perform mathematical operations on. Instead try this

```
x = [int(input('enter: ')) for i in range(5)]
even = [y for y in x  if y % 2 == 0]
print(even)
```

Comment: This is not working. Same error is coming invalid literal int

Comment: could you try to take above val list that I mentioned
ini_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4'] #Just took to rephrase the input that I got in coding

val = ("[{0}]".format(', '.join(map(str, ini_list))))

print(val)

#Outputlist
#[1,2,3,4]

Comment: he's already accepted one, dont fish for points.

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4'] #Just took to rephrase the input that I got in coding

val = ("[{0}]".format(', '.join(map(str, ini_list))))

print(val)

#Outputlist
#[1,2,3,4]
#The elements are in string format without quotes i.e. <class 'str'>
#This is the format I am getting as Input for the list

even_nos=[int(num) for num in val if num.isdigit() if int(num)%2==0]
print(even_nos)
```